# Searching in mongo by keys and values in whole unknown document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to search in mongo by keys and values in document with unknown structure?

For example:

```
{ 
  "accounting" : [   
                 { "firstName" : "John",  
                   "lastName"  : "Doe",
                   "age"       : 23 },

                 { "firstName" : "Mary",  
                   "lastName"  : "Smith",
                    "age"      : 32 }
             ],                            
  "sales"      : [ 
                 { "firstName" : "Sally", 
                   "lastName"  : "Green",
                    "age"      : 27 },

                 { "firstName" : "Jim",   
                   "lastName"  : "Galley",
                   "age"       : 41 }
             ] 
}
```

When I query by ''age'' I Would like to get document with keys age like above and also documents with age in text value. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the expected json response to post ?

Answer (score 0):

try with aggregation framework :

```
db['01'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                root:{$objectToArray:"$$ROOT"}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
              $or:[
              {"root.v.age":23},
              {"root.v.age":"23"}
            ]
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: {$arrayToObject:"$root"}
            }
        },
    ],
);
```